# Sporadic ActionController::UnknownFormat on ajax calls of a remote form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently using **rails 4 remote forms** with **json** responses:

```
respond_to do |format|   
  if read_only || @object.update_attributes(object_params)
    format.json { render json: {}, status: :ok }
  else
    format.json { render json: @object.errors.messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Most of the time it works well, but sometimes, **on chrome**, it gives a strange **ActionController::UnknownFormat** error.

This is very hard to trace since it is sporadic...

Anyone experienced this issue or has a solution?

EDIT:

As requested, from logs

```
Started PATCH "/objects/727" 
I, INFO -- : Processing by ObjectsController#update as JS

Started PATCH "/objects/727"
I, INFO -- : Processing by ObjectsController#update as HTML
```

it seams you are right, the failing request is not always JS, but I cannot think of a reason it doesn't always behave the same way and also why does it happen only on chrome?

Comment: Are you able to look in the log file to find the calls being made to the server?  I've had issues like this when I've forgotten to use `.json` calls in the past.

Comment: Ever figure out what this was? I'm seeing very similar issues with .js instead of .json.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a few months back, where my error aggregator was showing me similar errors. The errors were only for users accessing the site using IE7 and earlier browsers. The existing jquery version - 2.2.0 that I was using did not have support for older browsers, so I had to downgrade jquery version to 1.9.1, which solved the problem for me.